# Filter site.related_posts in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am very new to Jekyll and Ruby (yet, *very* excited).

Without using a plugin, I am trying to find a way to filter the `site.related_posts`.

For example, I am reading the post with title `Foo` and categories `A, B`.

The site contains in total 3 posts:

1. `Foo` (Categories: A, B)
2. `Bar` (Categories: A, C, D)
3. `Zoo` (Categories: B, F)

By the default, in Jekyll we do this:

> {% for post in site.related_posts limit:5 %}
>     {% endfor %}

However, the above code returns all the (3) posts.

A post contains many categories, so categories should be an array.

How can I modify the code and return only those whose categories intersect with the current post's categories?

(In this example, I would like the code to return only `Foo` and `Zoo`.)

Comment: Note that by default, "related posts" is actually just the most recent posts. Set `lsi: true` in _config.yml or run Jekyll with `--lsi` to get higher-quality results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have the ability to test this right now, but something like this will work given [Liquid's](https://github.com/shopify/liquid/wiki/liquid-for-designers) limited syntax:

```
{% for post in site.related_posts limit:5 %}
  {% assign match = false %}
  {% for category in post.categories %}
    {% if page.categories contains category %}
      {% assign match = true %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if match %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}                       
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: For even better results, I am trying the same code using `site.posts` instead of `site.related_posts limit:5`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great link to Liquid's documentation, that has opened my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure each post has a category in the YAML front matter, then add this to where you would like to show the post relating CATEGORY_NAME:

```
{% for post in site.categories.CATEGORY_NAME %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">
            <img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}">
            <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```